# No crea conexion con curl con parametros Get y en postman si trae resultados

Tags: php, postman

Tengo mi curl de esta manera:

```
$url='https://api.contifico.com/sistema/api/v1/producto?categoria_id=8J0yel6VNFN4bER7'; 
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: '.AUTORIZACION);
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Si envió la url `$url='https://api.contifico.com/sistema/api/v1/producto/` me trae resultados, pero si le envío con el parámetro no me hace ni conexión.
Realicé una prueba con Postman y si me trae resultados con parámetros.

Comment: Si te funciona en postman, entonces en la [barra lateral de la derecha](https://ibb.co/5M6hn9q) da click en el ícono `</>` y genera el código de la petición exacta de postman con curl.

Comment: genero la misma peticiónpuede ser por el tiempo de conexion que no me esta respetando